# How to set color of UISearchBar to match exactly what we want

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

[image]

I set the same color for the UISearchbar and the area surrounding it. Yet, the color of search bar seems to be dominated by something else.

Doing

```
self.srchBar.tintColor = [UIColor clColorOfUISearchBar];
self.srchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clColorOfUISearchBar];
```

Doesn't work. Even if I set that to something obvious like red, the red would be well, background. There is something grey on top of it.

There is no UISearchBar foreground color.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[searchBar setTranslucent:YES];
```